# Show random 3 from a list in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I'm listing some static contents as mentioned below. I would like to randomly showcase 3 items out of this 7 listings on every page refresh.

How can I go about doing this?

```
<div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 column-4" *ngIf="age >= 26 && age <= 60 && questions[1].answer_option == 2">
        <div>You are No 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 column-4" *ngIf="age >= 25 && age <= 60 && questions[1].answer_option == 2">
        <div>You are No 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 column-4" *ngIf="age >= 31 && age <= 60 && questions[1].answer_option == 2">
        <div>You are No 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 column-4" *ngIf="age >= 41 && age <= 60 && questions[1].answer_option == 2">
        <div>You are No 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 column-4" *ngIf="age >= 26 && age <= 50 && questions[1].answer_option == 2">
        <div>You are No 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 column-4" *ngIf="age >= 26 && age <= 60 && questions[1].answer_option == 2">
        <div>You are No 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 column-4" *ngIf="age >= 26 && age <= 60 && questions[1].answer_option == 2">
        <div>You are No 7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `afterViewInit` you can hide elements. [I made an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/show-random-3-from-a-list-in-angular-8)

Comment: Looks like this will do. Thank you so much :)

Comment: no problem :) just made a small change by only hiding the elements that are not selected instead of hide all and the select 3

Answer (score 1):

The correct (and efficient way) to do this is to create a pipe to splice your array of items at some random index.

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'randomShow'
})
export class RandomSlicePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], amountToShow?: any): any {
    if (!value || !Array.isArray(value) || !amountToShow) return value;

    let slicedArr = [...value],
        amountToRemove = value.length - amountToShow;
    while(amountToRemove--) {
      let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (slicedArr.length));
      slicedArr.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    return slicedArr;
  }
}
```

Of course that in order to use it you'll need to refactor your HTML to ngFor.

here's an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9exsd).